# Connecting to Windows network share without password

Tags: samba, file-sharing, cifs, dolphin

I want to access files in network Windows computer. When I click on "Network" place in Dolphin file manager I can see my workgroup and computers in "Samba shares" folder. But when I attempt to see files and folders in the Windows computer I am prompted to enter username and password. The problem is that for the Windows machine has not been set password and it is set not to require password while sharing. (There is not any problem while connecting from Windows OS.)

I have tried to enter blank username and password or enter Windows username, but this has not helped. I've also tried to mount this storage via `mount` and `mount.cifs` commands but without succes.

My OS is Kubuntu 16.10, Samba version number is 4.4.5.

Is there any way to connect to Windows share without entering password?

*UPDATE:* It is possible to open Windows folders via `smbclient` when entering empty password. But in Dolphin it still doesn't work.

*UPDATE 2 ‒ SOLUTION:* The problem is solved, at least partially, it is possible to mount network drive by command `sudo mount -t cifs //computer-name/shared-folder-name /mnt/mount-point/` and entering no remote computer password. Than is shared folder visible in Dolphin as device.

Comment: Does your windows machine have a user with the same name as your ubuntu user ?

Comment: No, there is different username.

Comment: Add your linux user to your Windows box, or vice versa. Try again when logged into linux as the same username.

Comment: I would like to preserve current accounts, because Windows computer is used by different person.  But I have found out that when I use smbclient I can open the share so it is probably Dolphin problem.

Comment: Maybe. But the idea behind users is that you (the real person) has an account on each computer you want to connect to. If you can connect using smbclient, well at least you have resolved your issue.